# Deleting filesystem from AWS- Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to launch a Amazon AWS EMR JAR Map Reduce Job. Therefore I get the Exception `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory s3://bi/stuff already exists`

In Hadoop I would enter A Command like:

```
hadoop fs -rmr /bi
```

The thing is that I haven't found a simular command in the AWS Commandline jet.
So can somebody please tell me how to delete the the Hadoop Filesystem in The Amazon S3 cloud

Answer (score 0):

From the [AWS doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html):

aws s3 rb s3://bucket-name

However, why don't you implement it in your jar via the AWS S3Client library?